# Why do I need to cast value of -1 as a char (when compiled for AVR microcontroller)

Tags: c, gcc, casting, avr

I am new to embedded C and C. I think I may be misunderstanding something basic here and would really appreciate some help.

I have the following function that outputs "return is -1" as I would expect if I run it on windows (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler).

```
#include <stdio.h>
char test();

int main()
{
    if (test() == -1 ) 
    {
        printf("return is -1");
    } 
    else 
    {
        printf("return is not -1");
    }
    return 0;
}

char test()
{
    return -1;
}
```

If I compile this for my AVR hardware, it outputs "return is not -1" which I cannot understand (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler, avr-gcc (WinAVR 20100110) 4.3.3).

If I change the first line to:

```
    if (test() == char(-1) ) {
```

then it outputs "return is -1" as expected for both scenarios.

Why do I need to explicitly cast -1 as a char?

Comment: Please add `#include <stdio.h>` for printf. Then please predeclare `char test();` before `main`. Then compile with `gcc -W -Wall`, and make sure there are 0 warnings. Does the problem still persist?

Comment: @pts comment is important. Without a declaration of `test()`, `main()` assumes `test()` is returning an `int`.  Yet `test()` only returns a `char`, the _rest_ of the return value is unknown.  So doing the `test() == -1` is comparing a partially value to `-1`.   Best to properly declare `test()` before calling it.

Comment: @chux it's not that it's "comparing a partial value". Because the declaration of the function and its definition do not match, the code simply invokes undefined behavior. No further reasoning is possible (or necessary, for that matter).

Comment: @user3477950 True - this is undefined behavior (UB).  In this case, further reasoning is _possible_ as the OP asserts that the compare works as expected when using `test() == char(-1)`.  This would occur if the correct _partially_ defined value was passed.  The reasoning though, as you suggest, is not necessary.  IAC: A compilation with ample warnings enabled would have detected this.

Comment: @pts I had the `#include <stdio.h>` and `char test();` lines in my original so I've edited it here to include them. So the problem was not that test() was partially declared. The problem was that I did not know there was a "signed char". I thought there was just "char" and "unsigned char". I have changed my test function to "signed char" and mow everything makes sense. Thanks @GigaWatt and @Keith Thompson

Comment: @user3688498 In general, before you ask a question, you should write a http://sscce.org/ code which demonstrates the problem, then make sure that compiling the code with warnings enabled yields 0 warnings, and you should copy-paste the entire http://sscce.org/ source file without any changes or simplifications. If you follow this, you'll get the answer you need faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue seems to be whether or not `char` is `signed` or `unsigned`, which happens to be [implementation specific](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054939/is-char-signed-or-unsigned-by-default).

You might be able to get around this by specifically using `signed char` wherever you need to use negative values.  Furthermore, it would be wise to ensure that you're using the same data types in your comparison (assuming `test()` now returns `signed char`):

```
if (test() == (signed char)(-1) )
```

Comment: @chux - I'll fix that.  I assumed they would rewrite `test()` to return `signed char`.

Comment: @chux I think it's quite clear what GigaWatt meant by "specifically using `signed char` wherever you need negative values". The "wherever" concerns, obviously, the return value of the function.

Comment: In `test() == -1` both sides are converted to an int. Converting `(unsigned char)-1` to an int yields 255, so `test() == 255` is true and `test() == -1` is false.

Comment: one comment: you should use header `inttypes.h` and write what you really need. in this case `int8_t`, `char` is for character data only.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the standard library, you'll find that most functions that deal with character values (like `getchar()`) return `int` results. I don't know what your `test` function is supposed to do, but it's likely that it would be better for it to return `int` rather than `char`.

The type `char` may be either signed or unsigned, depending on the implementation. If it's signed, its range is probably -128 .. +127; if it's unsigned, its range is probably 0 .. 255.

The `==` operator applies the "usual arithmetic conversions" to its operands. This means, among other things, that operands of integer types narrower than `int` are implicitly converted to `int` (if all the values of the type are in the range `INT_MIN`..`INT_MAX`) or to `unsigned int` (otherwise).

If plain `char` is signed, then the value returned by `test` is `(char)-1`, which is promoted to `-1` (of type `int`) and then compared to `-1` (also of type `int`) -- and the test succeeds.

If plain `char` is unsigned, then the value returned by `test` is `-1` *converted* to `char`. This conversion probably yields `255` (more precisely, it yields `CHAR_MAX`). So `test` returns `(char)255`, which is promoted to `int` -- and of course `255 != -1`.

Since `char` values, when used in expressions, are usually going to be promoted to `int` anyway, you might as well use type `int` in the first place.

It's hard to tell what your function:

```
char test() { return -1; }
```

is supposed to do in the first place. `-1` is not meaningful character value.

If what you really want is a very narrow signed integer, you can use `signed char`, and any promotion to `int` will preserve the correct value -- but there's no much point in using `signed char` rather than `int` unless you need to save space for large arrays.

(I've glossed over the fact that the `char` types can actually be wider than 8 bits; you're not likely to run into that issue unless you work with DSPs.)

Some more comments on your code:

Functions with no parameters should be defined with `(void)`, not `()`.  The `()` syntax is obsolescent; it indicates that the function has an unspecified but fixed number and type(s) of arguments.

You need to have a visible declaration of your `test` function *before* you call it. Either move the definition above the definition of `main`, or add a separate declaration (prototype) above `main`:

```
char test(void);
```

or, if you follow my advice:

```
int test(void);
```

(Actually your compiler should have warned you about the call to `test` with no visible declaration. Find out how to increase your compiler's warning levels so it tells you about errors like that.)

Comment: Thanks @Keith Thomspon for the answer here and for the tips. I did have a declaration for the signed `test` function which I've added to my original question. I'm using (signed) char rather than int because I'm tight on space so went for the smallest and, yes, re your void comment. The actual function accepts parameters and returns the -1 based on some tests, I was just trying to pare it down to where I thought the problem was for this forum. Thanks

Comment: @user3688498: Using a `signed char` rather than an `int` for a single object or function result is unlikely to save any space. It's going to be promoted to `int` in most contexts, which could be costly in both time and code size. And depending on the CPU, code to access a single byte might be more expensive than code to access a word. If you declare a `signed char` object, it's likely that the three bytes following it in memory are going to be wasted because whatever follows it may require word alignment.

Comment: interesting. I'm using Atmel ATMega328p which is an 8-bit micro-controller. I can see how your comments would be true for 16 bit processor. Do you know if this would be the same in an 8 bit environment? This embedded world is a whole new kettle of fish to me as an experienced high-level windows developer :-)

Comment: maybe I want int8_t not signed char

Comment: @user3688498: `int8_t` and `signed char` are very likely the same type. Use whichever one makes more sense based on its name. If it's integer data, use `int8_t`; if it's character data you probably want plain `char`, but then you'll have to deal with its implementation-defined signedness. Yes, the performance issues could be different for an 8-bit embedded processor -- and embedded C compiler don't always follow the C standard rules for promotions. Consult your compiler's documentation.

Answer (score -1):

because the return type on test() is a char. the default return type is int.

Comment: There is no "default return type"; C99 dropped the "implicit `int`" rule, and it's not particularly relevant anyway.